# How to remove or disable super weapons in C&C Generals Zero Hour

Tags: mods, origin, command-and-conquer-generals, command-and-conquer-zero-hour

I would like to play skirmish and co-op games with a friend against multiple AI players. Disabling SW will allow us to war against more AI using conventional weapons.

I would like to disable all players from having or using super weapons.

I have tried a few solutions that included

- Dropping a custom NOSW commandset.ini in the data/ini
- Moving and extracting INIZH.big and dropping the files in the data/ini folder and overwriting the a custom NOSW commandset.ini

It seems to be that the Origin version of Command And Conquer Generals Zero Hour cannot be modified to remove super weapons.

Everytime I tried a mod [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p8azMnUuJY) or [here](http://www.moddb.com/mods/command-and-conquer-untitled/downloads/cc-untitled-20-beta-no-installer-easier) or [here](http://commandandconquer.filefront.com/file/No_Superweapons_Mod;25676); the game crashes with a generic message such as check your hardware requirements. Removing the mod make the game work correctly.

**Additional**
The most I can configure is "Limit SW" which allows each player one SW.
The path to starting a game is Multiplayer/Online/Custom Game.
There is no other options besides the aforementioned that allows me to configure the game except how many are playing, who they are (USA/CHINA/PLA) and which map.

Comment: Isn't there an option when starting skirmish, where you can define the highest tech-lvl you can build? I don't know, I haven't played Generals in years. Though I faintly remember *C&C: Red Alert* featuring such an option. Setting the tech-lvl to the second-to-highest would disable Superweapons in that case.

Comment: no other options :( I have updated my question.

Comment: I see, tough luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think theres such an option. But you can workaround that maybe: be faster in building  sws and use them just to destroy the ais sw ^^ did it that way always

Comment: This workaround is working for us. We build 2 SW each.

Comment: Glad to hear ^^

Comment: But remember... for glas sw you need three of yours ^^

Comment: @ekonion Or just use your Command center Strike Bombers + 1 SW. That won't destroy a GLA SW completely but it'll buy you enough time to repower your SW and Strike Bombers to do it over again indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion: raise the price of the SW to an unreachable point. This can be done with Generals, I doubt it'll work with ZH. I used to fiddle with the prices using `notepad++`, but then you need to transfer the same file to all workstations.

Comment: what's the name of the file that needs to be edited?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was something like `BIG.INI` or `INI.BIG`